# Get data from with dynamic where argument

Tags: c#, database, linq

A table in a database that contains three columns, Id, Word, Opposite (in the context below the "Word" and "Opposite" is the actual data/values in the table)

The values from Word is get by a LINQ-query in a controller and sent to the view and presented as list. Next to the Word there is a `@EditorFor` where the user is  supposed to type in the opposite.

In the view a DisplayFor (that's Word) and a EditorFor (an input box) gets a zero-based index. The user input is sent to the controller that passes the model as parameter. From the model the guessed Opposites is found and put in a `List<string> and is compared to another`List`that contains the actual values from the column`Word`.

As of now I can get the user input from the `@ÈditorFor` and from the data I have I can get the correct guessed `Opposites`and the wrongly guessed `Opposites`. But I can´t get the values from the column `Word` from the same row of `Opposite`that is either correct or wrong.

Opposite is something like

```
var list = oppositeListFromDB.Except(guessesFromUser);
```

My initial thought was make another LINQ query with the values that is the correct opposite and select the matching Word. To clarify If the user guesses wrong on row 5 and 6, the *words* "Dry" and "Old" is used as a where parameter in a list. But the parameters must be dynamic and how do i solve this? I've tried something like below but it does not work. Am I thinking correctly or is there a better approach?

```
var q = from a in db.Table
        where a.Opposite.Contains(list)
        select a.Word;
```

Using MVC 5 and have a model like below, the List is used in another part of the projekt. Could I use it for my problem here btw?

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public string Opposite { get; set; }
    public List<WordCl> mWords { get; set; }

}
public class WordCL
{   public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public string Opposite { get; set; }
}





+----+-------+----------+
| ID | Word  | Opposite |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 | Rain  | Sun      |
|  2 | Clean | Dirty    |
|  3 | Light | Dark     |
|  4 | Hot   | Cold     |
|  5 | Wet   | Dry      |
|  6 | Young | Old      |
+----+-------+----------+
```

Comment: _There are input fields for the input with id so it can be matched with the correct Word_, so you can get the `id`, and then get the `word`?

Comment: I have updated my post as I had it pretty wrong, the "id" were in fact indexes that has nothing to do with the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a hard time visualizing which data you have available and which data you're trying to collect.

You can use an anonymous type object to select fields that interest you:

```
var result = from a in db
             where a.Word == "..."
             select new { a.Opposite, a.Word };

foreach (var r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.Opposite);
    Console.WriteLine(r.Word);
}
```

By the way (can't comment):

```
where a.Opposite.Contains(list)
```

Shouldn't this be `where list.Contains(a.Opposite)`, as otherwise you'd be calling `Contains` on a string?

Comment: It was the `where list.Contains(a.Opposite)` that fixed everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var guessed = foo;
var opposite = db.Table.AsEnumerable().Where(x.Opposite == guessed).FirstOrDefault();

id(opposite != null)
{
    //to get the word from the opposite
    var wordFromOpposite = opposite.Word;

    if(!db.Table.AsEnumerable().Any(x => x.Word == word && x.Opposite == guessed))
    {
       ...Notify the user he guessed wrong
    }
}
```

where `word` is the one displayed to the user and `foo` is the value entered by the user.

Comment: Im not familiar with lambda so i dont understand it all but the `if statement` check if there is values in `Word` column that matches the displayed word AND values in `Opposite` column that matches the INPUT from user. Correct? I removed the `if-statement` and put  `var bar = !db...` and it gave med both true and false regardless the user input. I need the actual words/values. Maybe im misunderstanding  it? I've updated my OP btw bc i realised it was correct. Does it matter here?

Comment: you were right about the if statement. now what I thought you provide users with a word and they input the opposite word they think. then you notify them in case they were wrong, right?

Comment: And I updated my OP again as it was not really clear what i wanted to do or could do with the data.

Comment: this line will help you to get the word from the opposite entered by the user db.Table.AsEnumerable().Where(x.Opposite == guessed).FirstOrDefault();.Now, FirstOrDefault() it will return the Model if exists or null otherwise. That's why the null checking. Then to get the corresponding Word to the Opposite, you just do (model) opposite.Word;

Comment: I think there is something wrong somewhere, probably on my part and i left something out. The `word` in the first query doesnt get any values, only the namespace and class name of String it self i think. But i've converted it from IEnumerble, tolist and tostring maybe it went wrong somewhere. And the x in the first query should be a x=>.Opposite, right? Anyway I solved it by using the user apks last row of code. But thanks anyway, I really appreciate it!

Comment: you're right, it should be x => x.Opposite. Thanks for upvoting